# Shape Mismatch XGBoost Regressor

Tags: python, data-science, xgboost

I have trained an XGBoost Regressor model on data that has a different shape to the test data I intend to predict on. Is there a way to go around this or a model that can tolerate feature mismatches?

The input training data and test data got mismatched during One Hot Encoding of categorical features.

```
best_xgb = xgb.XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
             colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, enable_categorical=False,
             gamma=0, gpu_id=-1, importance_type=None,
             interaction_constraints='', learning_rate=0.05, max_delta_step=0,
             max_depth=6, min_child_weight=10,monotone_constraints='()', n_estimators=400, n_jobs=4,
             num_parallel_tree=1, predictor='auto', random_state=0, reg_alpha=0,
             reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, subsample=1, tree_method='exact',
             validate_parameters=1, verbosity=None)

best_xgb.fit(X, y)

best_xgb.predict(test_data)
```

I get the following error:
[Shape Mismatch Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SylRw.png)

Comment: Your `test_data` should have the same shape as your train data. Maybe some categorical features appear in the train data but not in the test data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check where 249-235=14 features are in test data.
Or fit on same data
`best_xgb.fit(X[test_data.columns], y)`

Comment: Fitting on same data worked thanks @circassia_ai